# Classic ASP, SQL Server, Windows Azure, Radio button UPDATE SET command - Unexpected behavior

Tags: sql, azure, asp-classic

I've inherited a classic ASP app and migrated to Windows Azure, SQL and all things work OK -except- one odd issue maybe you'd know about?

### Scenario

Select rows of data order by matching unique ID - present to user interface. Two rows per 'set'. One already marked in field 'MasterSelect' with a 'Y'. ASP code called via radio button OnClick clears (or should) both fields in both records, then sets the new record's field to have a 'Y' whether it's the top or bottom selection. A toggle if you will.

Works like a charm on (local) and half-way works on Azure.

```
**(local)** ('x' = choose radio button)

x #1 -->  'Y'
  #2 -->  ' '

  #1 -->  ' '
x #2 -->  'Y'

x #1 -->  'Y'
  #2 -->  ' '

**(Azure)**

x #1 -->  'Y'
  #2 -->  ' '

  #1 -->  'Y'  <--- (Should be blank)
x #2 -->  'Y'

x #1 -->  'Y'
  #2 -->  ' '
```

Here's the code:

```
' If updating the master select field then need to clear all previous selects for that dupid
if updfield="masterselect" then
    strSQL = "select FileName,DupeID from OnLineContactsM where OnLineRecID=" & keyvalue
    cn.execute("exec insertactivity '','','ajaxUpdate.asp','" & strSQL & "'")
    set rs=cn.execute(strSQL)

    if not rs.eof then
        fn = rs("FileName")
        DID = rs("DupeID")
        strSQL = "update OnLineContactsM set MasterSelect='' where FileName like'" & fn & "' and DupeID='" & DID & "'"
        cn.execute(strSQL)
        'cn.execute("exec insertactivity '','','ajaxUpdate.asp','" & DID & "'")
    end if
end if
```

The behavior on the remote location is that the top row **never** gets cleared out but the bottom row always works as expected. AND if I manually run the exact line of code manually, regardless of pointing at (local) or (remote) the code runs flawlessly - on both platforms?!?!?

I thought maybe there'd be some code elsewhere than what I've presented that might reset the first record but would then be unable to explain why the (local) copy did not exhibit that behavior. In other words because things work as expected and always have ***until*** Azure came into the picture we were golden.

So, my conclusion would naturally lead me to some environmentally-related cause but I'm at the point where I need wiser heads than mine apparently is.

I've looked at this from all sorts of angles (cache, indexes, code compare, etc) and have concluded bug, incompatibility or environment-related issue. I have search almost all day without anything definitive.

Would anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing the behavioral differences?

TIA!!!

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- DB Collation may be different (case sensitive)
- Some db configs may introduce bugs like `SET ARITHIGNORE` or `SET NOCOUNT`
- Transactions: Maybe Azure SQL it's adding an outer transac that not commiting